# stylus-Angular 5:angular material changing theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

Currently my project is using "stylus" CSS pre-processor and not SCSS, I want to use angular material themes and switch the Themes. I can all documentation using SCSS but not stylus, Can anyone help me if it is possible to implement the Angular material switch theme logic using Angular 5 + Angular Material + Stylus?
Please help me with any documentation or example

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you had any luck?

Answer (score -1):

Try to create global variables that will determine colors, using these variables you will be able to quickly change the color of the theme. 
A good way is to edit the angular color palette.

Comment: How this addresses the question?